# How can I download data depending on reactive values in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm new to RShiny. I created a model in R and wanted to make it user-friendly using RShiny.

It plots some histograms and moving average graphs (currently working), but I also want to be able to download my simulation when I click the "simulate" button and trigger reactive values.

As I'm using reactiveValues(), and I use some separate info for plotting, I've created "my.download" from the reactive values I obtain each time I hit the "Simulate button". But the downloadable .csv file gives me two columns (I'm using cbind with 5 vectors), with absolutely odd numbers. If I simulate 1000 cases, it gives me 5000 rows; if 2000 cases, 10000 rows, etc.

This is the part of my code related to the .csv file I want to convert my data to.

```r
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
### My functions ###

claims.frequency = function(iterations, dist, lambda, size, prob){
  freq = rep(NA,iterations)
  if(dist == "Poisson"){freq_dt = data.table(i=1:iterations)[,list(freq=rpois(n=1,lambda=lambda)),by=i]}
  else if(dist == "Negative Binomial"){freq_dt = data.table(i=1:iterations)[,list(freq=rnbinom(n=1,size=size,prob=prob)),by=i]}
  return(freq_dt$freq)
}

claims.severity <- function(frequency,dist,meanlog,sdlog,shape,scale,rate,percentile){
  sever = rep(NA,length(frequency))
  moving_average = rep(NA,length(frequency))
  moving_percentile = rep(NA,length(frequency))
  df = rep(NA,length(frequency))
  if(dist=="Lognormal"){sever_dt=data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(sever=sum(rlnorm(n=frequency[i],meanlog=meanlog,sdlog=sdlog))),by=i]}
  else if(dist=="Gamma"){sever_dt=data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(sever=sum(rgamma(n=frequency[i],shape=shape,rate=rate))),by=i]}
  else if(dist=="Exponential"){sever_dt=data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(sever=sum(rexp(n=frequency[i],rate=1/rate))),by=i]}
  else if(dist=="Weibull"){sever_dt=data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(sever=sum(rweibull(n=frequency[i],shape=shape,scale=scale))),by=i]}

  moving_average_dt = data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(moving_average=mean(sever_dt$sever[1:i])),by=i]
  moving_percentile_dt = data.table(i=1:length(frequency))[,list(moving_percentile=quantile(sever_dt$sever[1:i],probs=percentile)),by=i]

  df = cbind(frequency,sever_dt$sever,moving_average_dt$moving_average,moving_percentile_dt$moving_percentile)
  colnames(df) = c("# Claims","Aggregate Claims Value","Moving Average","Moving Percentile")
  return(as.data.frame(df))
}

### UI ###

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Simulator'),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(inputId="n", "Iterations", value = 250500, min = 1000, max = 500000, step = 500, round = TRUE, ticks = TRUE),
    radioButtons("freq.dist", "Frequency Distributions:",
                 c("Poisson (\\(\\lambda\\))" = "P",
                   "Negative Binomial (n, p)" = "B")),
    numericInput("paramfreq1","\\(\\lambda\\), if Poisson; or n, if Negative Binomial",0),
    numericInput("paramfreq2","p",0),
    radioButtons("sever.dist", "Severity Distributions:",
                 c("Lognormal (\\(\\mu\\ ,  \\sigma\\))" = "L",
                   "Gamma (\\(\\alpha\\ ,  \\beta\\))" = "G",
                   "Exponential (\\(\\lambda\\))" = "E",
                   "Weibull (\\(\\alpha\\ ,  \\beta\\))" = "W")),
    numericInput("paramsever1","\\(\\mu\\), if Lognormal; \\(\\alpha\\), if Gamma or Weibull; or \\(\\lambda\\), if Exponential",0),
    numericInput("paramsever2","\\(\\sigma\\), if Lognormal; or \\(\\beta\\), if Gamma or Weibull",0),
    actionButton("simulate","Simulate"),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
  )
)

### SERVER ###

server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(my.freq = 0,
                       my.total.claims = 0,
                       my.moving.average = 0,
                       my.moving.percentile = 0,
                       my.download = 0)

  observeEvent(input$simulate,
               {
                 my.freq <- switch(input$freq.dist,
                                   "P" = claims.frequency(iterations = input$n,
                                                          dist = "Poisson",
                                                          lambda = input$paramfreq1),
                                   "B" = claims.frequency(iterations = input$n,
                                                          dist = "Negative Binomial",
                                                          size = input$paramfreq1,
                                                          prob = input$paramfreq2))

                 my.sever <- switch(input$sever.dist,
                                    "L" = claims.severity(frequency = my.freq,
                                                          dist = "Lognormal",
                                                          meanlog = input$paramsever1,
                                                          sdlog = input$paramsever2,
                                                          percentile = .995),
                                    "G" = claims.severity(frequency = my.freq,
                                                          dist = "Gamma",
                                                          shape = input$paramsever1,
                                                          rate = input$paramsever2,
                                                          percentile = .995),
                                    "E" = claims.severity(frequency = my.freq,
                                                          dist = "Exponential",
                                                          rate = input$paramsever1,
                                                          percentile = .995),
                                    "W" = claims.severity(frequency = my.freq,
                                                          dist = "Weibull",
                                                          shape = input$paramsever1,
                                                          scale = input$paramsever2,
                                                          percentile = .995))

                 rv$my.freq <- as.numeric(my.freq)
                 rv$my.total.claims <- as.numeric(my.sever$`Aggregate Claims Value`)
                 rv$my.moving.average <- as.numeric(my.sever$`Moving Average`)
                 rv$my.moving.percentile <- as.numeric(my.sever$`Moving Percentile`)
                 rv$my.download <- (as.numeric(cbind(1:length(my.freq), my.sever$`# Claims`,my.sever$`Aggregate Claims Value`,my.sever$`Moving Average`,my.sever$`Moving Percentile`))) ### PROBLEM HERE ###
               }
  )

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste('simulation-', Sys.time(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.table(x = rv$my.download, file, dec = "," , sep = ";")
    })
}
```

I expect an output with correct columns (and colnames too, but when I try to add it it returns the following error):

```r
Warning: Error in colnames<-: attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

But my .csv file goes like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uru59.png

While the expected output is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j6tK.png

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Update: code is working now. I just used as.numeric() individually in each vector in my.download. Then I set row.names to FALSE in write.table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the entire problem, but I think part of the issue is that you're wrapping your call to `cbind()` in `as.numeric()`

For example
    `as.numeric(cbind(1:3, 4:6))`
returns a numeric vector, where 
    `cbind(1:3, 4:6)` returns a matrix. You could also use `data.frame(col_name1 = vector1, col_name2 = vector2...)` to ensure rv$mydownload is in the correct format for export.